# npm run build error for bootstrap4 UI Framework Web project

Tags: deployment, npm, build, npm-scripts

Please I need some help here.

After I type `npm run build` to my terminal of windows 10, I get the following errors:

> 'imagemin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file. npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR!
>   errno 1 npm ERR! confusion@1.0.0 imagemin: `imagemin img/* -o
>   dist/img` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the
>   confusion@1.0.0 imagemin script. npm ERR! This is probably not a
>   problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above. npm
>   ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\ndunga\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-10-19T16_46_04_328Z-debug.log
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! confusion@1.0.0
>   build: `npm run clean && npm run copyfonts && npm run imagemin && npm
>   run usemin` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the
>   confusion@1.0.0 build script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem
>   with npm. There is likely additional logging output above. npm ERR! A
>   complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\ndunga\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-10-19T16_46_04_381Z-debug.log

Here is my package.json file

```json
{
  "name": "confusion",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is a website for Ristorante Con Fusion",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run watch:all",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "scss": "node-sass -o css/ css/",
    "watch:scss": "onchange \"css/*.scss\" -- npm run scss",
    "watch:all": "parallelshell \"npm run watch:scss\" \"npm run lite\"",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "copyfonts": "copyfiles -f node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/* dist/fonts",
    "imagemin": "imagemin img/* -o dist/img",
    "usemin": "usemin contactus.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/contactus.html && usemin aboutus.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/aboutus.html && usemin index.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/index.html",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run copyfonts && npm run imagemin && npm run usemin"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "cssmin": "^0.4.3",
    "htmlmin": "0.0.7",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "onchange": "^3.2.1",
    "parallelshell": "^3.0.2",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "uglifyjs": "^2.4.11",
    "usemin-cli": "^0.5.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have [imagemin](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin) package installed.

```
npm install imagemin --save
```

Comment: `imagemin` is installed globally so it is not in `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

install `imagemin-cli` and use it like `"imagemin": "imagemin img/ --out-dir=dist/img"` in `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (Windows 10):

Open index.js file (path: \Bootstrap4\conFusion\node_modules\parallelshell\index.js)
At line 105, instead of "cwd: process.versions.node", change to "cwd: parseInt(process.versions.node)"